# beginner javascript algorithm: method forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, methods

I'm doing this javascript algorithm challenge which has this array `['cat', 'game', 'socks']` and it has an image of what it must return:

```
[
  "******cat******",
  "*******game*******",
  "********socks********"
]
```

as you see, each word has a * more than the previous word, so not all words should be equal, would you use forEach? or how would you do it?

Comment: You can use map or foreach function

Comment: What will be the use of  ```/* [ "\ncat\n", "\ngame*\n*", "*****\nsocks\n*******" ] */```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not going to originally submit an answer, but why not.

My approach would be using a for loop to iterate the list once and maintaining a string that gets incremented with a `*` for every `for` call.

In big-o notation, this would be an O(n) solution.

```js
let data = ['cat', 'game', 'socks']
let buffer = '*****';

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = `${buffer}\n*${data[i]}*\n${buffer}`;
  buffer += '*';
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it via [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**String.repeat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
let data = ['cat', 'game', 'socks']

let result = data.map((d,i) => {
  let s = `*`.repeat(i)
  let e = `*****${s}\n*${d}*\n${s}*****`
  return e
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: For performance, `for()` will execute quicker.

Comment: ...and is probably more appropriate for a total beginner.